# Create many AWS instances with Ansible, 'count' does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have this playbook:

```
---
# Run it like this:
# ansible-playbook --extra-vars '{"VAR":"var-value", "VAR":"var-value"}' playbook-name.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    instance_tag : "{{ TAG }}"
    instances_num: 2
  tasks:
  - name: Create new AWS instances
    local_action:
      module: ec2
      region: us-east-1 
      key_name: integration 
      instance_type: m3.medium 
      image: ami-61dcvfa 
      group: mysecgroup 
      instance_tags:
        Name: "{{ instance_tag }}"
    with_sequence: count = {{ instances_num | int }}
```

When I run it it throws this:

```
TASK: [Create new AWS instances] **********************************************
fatal: [localhost] => unknown error parsing with_sequence arguments: u'count = 1'

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

What am I doing wrong?
I have tried with `2` also, but throws the same error. 
I have tried also with `"{{instances_num}}"` but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ec2 module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html) has a `count` parameter that you can use directly rather than trying to [loop the task over a sequence](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-integer-sequences).

You can use it like this:

```
---
# Run it like this:
# ansible-playbook --extra-vars '{"VAR":"var-value", "VAR":"var-value"}' playbook-name.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    instance_tag : "{{ TAG }}"
    instances_num: 2
  tasks:
  - name: Create new AWS instances
    local_action:
      module: ec2
      region: us-east-1 
      key_name: integration 
      instance_type: m3.medium 
      image: ami-61dcvfa 
      group: mysecgroup 
      instance_tags:
        Name: "{{ instance_tag }}"
      count: "{{ instances_num }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the code from some tutorial that I now cannot find and it didnt work.